# Python Pandas Calculate Two Columns Containing String

Tags: python, pandas

[Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SKVy.png)--[pandas read_excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dG9H.png)

Hi,

I am trying to calculate the difference of column C (unnamed: 2) and column D (unnamed: 3), and put the result in column E. I have attached a Excel screenshot and a pandas read Excel screenshot.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas

# load excel file
df1 = pandas.read_excel("Trial.xlsx")

# column C minus column D, and store result in column E
df1["total"] = df1["unnamed: 2"] - df1["unnamed: 3"]

print(df1)
```

The code does not work because column C and D contain string on C4 and D4. I am wondering if there is any way to bypass row 4 or do the calculation starting from row 5 (index 4).

Comment: Refer to the guidelines to make the question reproducible  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would use the parameter `skiprows` in the `read_excel` method [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df1 = pandas.read_excel("Trial.xlsx", skiprows=4)
```

You can also use `pandas.to_numeric` with the parameter `errors='coerce'` to make all non numeric values into `nan`s. [See documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)  If you use the above code, pandas should pick up the header names and you can use the following:

```
df1["total"] = (
    pandas.to_numeric(df1["Debit"], errors='coerce') 
    - pandas.to_numeric(df1["Credit"], errors='coerce')
)
```

Comment: Thank you. The first code works. After adding the “total” column, can I save the results back to the original file, but still keep the original title”ABC inc”.

Answer (score 0):

one way to accomplish it would be to make the values in the column as float

```
df1["unnamed: 2"] = df1["unnamed: 2"].str.replace('([^\d\.])+','', regex=True ).replace('',np.nan).astype(float)
df1["unnamed: 3"] = df1["unnamed: 3"].str.replace('([^\d\.])+','', regex=True ).replace('',np.nan).astype(float)


df1["total"] = df1["unnamed: 2"] - df1["unnamed: 3"]
```

if you post the excel as a downloadable, i an run the solution and provide the Result